# MYSQL - Como hacer que una columna SELECT utilice datos de otra columna en una misma consulta

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente caso: una tabla que tiene dos campos relacionados con otra tabla y a su vez está relacionada con otra.

```
create table Usuario(
id int auto_increment primary key,
nombre varchar(100));

create table Participacion(
id int auto_increment primary key,
usuarioid int,
torneoid int,
FOREIGN KEY (usuarioid) REFERENCES Usuario(id),
FOREIGN KEY (torneoid) REFERENCES Torneo(id);

create table Partida(
id int auto_increment primary key,
jugador1 int,
jugador2 int,
llave int,
FOREIGN KEY (jugador1) REFERENCES Participacion(id),
FOREIGN KEY (jugador2) REFERENCES Participacion(id));
```

Lo que deseo hacer es una consulta donde me muestre, en una misma fila, los campos jugador1 y jugador2 (de la tabla partida) con su respectivo nombre de la tabla Usuario. De la siguiente manera:

```
jugador1      | jugador2      | nombre1       | nombre2
--------------------------------------------------------------
3             | 2             | jugador6      | jugador8
```

Quise utilizar los datos de la consulta, pero me indica que devuelve más de un dato en la consulta:

```
SELECT p.jugador1 as participacion1, 
p.jugador2 as participacion2,
(SELECT u.nombre FROM Usuario u, Partida p, Participacion part
WHERE p.jugador1 = part.id AND u.id = part.usuarioid
AND p.jugador1 = participacion1) as nombre1,
(SELECT u.nombre FROM Usuario u, Partida p, Participacion part
WHERE p.jugador2 = part.id AND u.id = part.usuarioid
AND p.jugador2 = participacion2) as nombre2,
FROM Participacion part, Partida p
WHERE part.id = p.jugador1;
```

Comment: Creo que quieres utilizar ´JOIN´ o no ??, esto permite unir tablas a partir de un dato en comun (muchas veces un ID), de este modo, el ID 1 de la tabla Usuario, es el mismo ID 1 de la tabla partida, y puedes invocar ambos datos en una misma query

Comment: p.jugador2 = participacion2 es la misma variable dos veces.. de ahi que te diga que salen muchos registros...

Comment: No hay alguna manera de que el p.jugador2 de la subconsulta pueda compararse con el particiipacion2 de la tabla de la consulta principal?

Comment: si, pero fijate que probablemente queres comparar particion2 con otra cosa en los subquerys

Comment: Si necesitas relacionar una tabla con otras dos tablas, entonces lo lógico es **que pongas esa tabla dos veces en la consulta, con dos alias distintos** y uses cada alias para relacionarla con la tabla que quieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que tu caso se resolverá mas rápido si generas inner join entre las tablas que necesitas.

Genero 4 inner join, 2 por cada jugador que tienes en tu tabla de partida, para obtener el registro de tu nombre de usuario.

```
SELECT p.jugador1 as participacion1, 
    p.jugador2 as participacion2,
    u1.nombre,
    u2.nombre
FROM Partida P
    INNER JOIN Participacion Part1 on p.jugador1 =part1.id
    INNER JOIN Usuario U1 ON part1.usuarioid =U1.id
    INNER JOIN Participacion Part2 on p.jugador2 =part2.id
    INNER JOIN Usuario U2 ON part2.usuarioid =U2.id
```

Comment: Esto lo resolvió completamente, muchas gracias.